# Running multiple instance of Firefox but first opened window don't close after Selenium test has run

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver

I am working on a project where I try some tests on yahoo, gmail and hotmail logins and I open multiple instances to test a list of users. Here is my code :

```
import time
import sys
import unittest
from profiles import get_profiles, initialize_driver
from database import execute_query
import threading

class BaseLoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.profile_directories = get_profiles()
        self.driver = None

    def perform_login(self, login_function):
        user_ids = sys.argv[1]
        sleep_time = int(sys.argv[3])
        query =f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ({user_ids})"
        rows = execute_query(query)
        for row in rows:
            username = row[1]
            password = row[2]
            web_driver = sys.argv[2]
            self.driver = initialize_driver("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Yahoo_test_UI\\Helper\\Profiles\\"+str(row[0]), web_driver)
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            t = threading.Thread(target=login_function, args=(self.driver, username, password))
            t.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        self.driver.quit()
```

But the problem is when I use firefox as a browser it closes all the windows except the first opened one. I din't find this problem with Chrome or Edge.
How I can solve this ?